# Resize Panel according to Label size

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Panel with a Label inside.

Sometimes, the Label is very long and the panel must be resized.

I have set the Autosize property to true for both controls, but ....

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Are you sure there's not a third control that you're forgetting to set AutoSize for (a nested panel)?

Comment: Also, make sure Dock is set to None for the Label.

Answer (score 2):

You also must set `AutoSize` to `true` for the containing containers as well, up to the window.

My last attempt in doing so involved quite a bit of redesigning the form with TableLayoutPanel and the like since Dock/Anchor and AutoSize don't seem to mix well.

Answer (score 1):

> I have set the Autosize property to true for both controls, but ....

I can tell from the "but" what you are asking for.  That's the AutoEllipsis property of the Label.  Set it to true and set the MaximumSize property so the label cannot get bigger than its container.  The user will see ... so she'll realize the text is truncated.  She'll hover the mouse over the label to get a tooltip with the full text.

Letting everything grow to accommodate a label is drastically impractical.  You typically can manipulate MaximumSize to let it grow vertically for a while, up to a point.

Comment: Having to hover over a label to know what it reads is dratically impractical, too. Only for the user. Usually I'd argue in favor of the user in such situations ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem, and here is a code for you. Assuming your Panel is anchored to the form (top,left,bottom,right), it is the form that needs to be resized, not the Panel.

```
    public static void FitPanel(Panel pnl)
    {
        int maxright = 0;
        int maxbottom = 0;
        foreach (Control ctl in pnl.Controls)
        {
            maxright = (ctl.Right > maxright ? ctl.Right : maxright);
            maxbottom = (ctl.Bottom > maxbottom ? ctl.Bottom : maxbottom);
        }
        int deltabottom = pnl.Bottom - (pnl.Top + maxbottom);
        int deltaright = pnl.Right - (pnl.Left + maxright);
        Form frm = pnl.FindForm();
        frm.SuspendLayout();
        frm.Height = frm.Height - deltabottom;
        frm.Width = frm.Width - deltaright;
        frm.ResumeLayout();
    }
```